# Core data loses relationship data after quitting app

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

This seems really strange to me.  I have a core data database.  I have two tables, let's call them tableA and tableB.
tableA has lots of data, maybe thousands of records.
tableB has a few records.
tableB has 9 relationships to tableA.  Each of these relationships is one-many to tableB.

This all works fine while the app is running; however, if I terminate the app (in xCode, stop), many of the relationships become empty.  And it's very consistent.  The most recent record in tableB is always ok and the older records are all missing data for some of the relationships.

The relationships in tableB are one-many.  Initially I created inverse one-many relationships from tableA.  After noticing this issue, I removed the inverse relationships.  The app still runs fine until I terminate and restart it, although I do get warnings without the inverses.

I have made sure to do a save on the context and I have checked context.hasChanges and it is false.

Any help would be appreciated.  This is my hair-puller for today.

Answer (score 0):

When you hard-kill an app like that from the debugger, you can't possibly expect it to go through the normal termination processing.

This is even more pronounced when you use UIManagedDocument or any type of asynchronous save operations.

What happens when you terminate the app on the device, via the normal app-termination methods?